# Disable JMS for profile

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

In Springboot 2 I can do something like this to disable the embedded servlet container:

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none
```

Now I am looking for a similar setting to disable JMS. Currently I am using a profile, something like this:

```
@Profile("!nojms")
public class MQListener {
...
```

and then using an `application-lala.yaml` with content:

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none

  profiles:
    active: nojms
```

But now when I use the profile "lala" then the JMS listener is still starting.

Comment: How are you activating the profiles at runtime?

Comment: just via command line `--spring.profiles.active=lala` but I do not want to directly expose `--spring.profiles.active=lala,nojms` since this would affect various container builds which are out of my control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're activating via CLI args the `profiles.active` won't get triggered as you've essentially already activated a profile.

You can add `spring.profiles.include` to the `application-lala` to unconditionally active other profiles.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles

> The spring.profiles.active property follows the same ordering rules as other properties: The highest PropertySource wins. This means that you can specify active profiles in application.properties and then replace them by using the command line switch.
>
> Sometimes, it is useful to have profile-specific properties that add to the active profiles rather than replace them. The spring.profiles.include property can be used to unconditionally add active profiles. The SpringApplication entry point also has a Java API for setting additional profiles (that is, on top of those activated by the spring.profiles.active property). See the setAdditionalProfiles() method in SpringApplication.

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none

  profiles:
      include: nojms
```